# Let $f$ be the function such that for every real number $t$, $\int_t^{f(t)} \frac{x^4}{1+x^2}=2$. Calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I can take the indefinite integral of this to get $\int \frac{x^4}{1+x^2} dx= \frac{x^3}{3}-x+\arctan(x)+C$ by doing long division and normal integration. The issue I have is how to use find the function $f$, or compute the requested limit.

Answer (score 1):

By assumption, $g(f(t))-g(t)=2$, where:
$$g(t)=\int_0^t \frac{x^4}{1+x^2} dx$$

As $t\to\infty$, we have $g(t)\sim\frac{t^3}3\to\infty$.
Then $g(f(t))\sim g(t)\to\infty$, hence $f(t)\to\infty$ as well.
Consequently,
$$f(t)^3/3\sim g(f(t))\sim g(t)\sim t^3/3$$
from which $f(t)\sim t$.

Moreover, $g'(t)\sim t^2$ as $t\to\infty$, hence from $g'(f(t))f'(t)=g'(t)$, follows
$$f'(t)=\frac{g'(t)}{g'(f(t))}\sim\left(\frac t{f(t)}\right)^2\to 1$$
as $t\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^4/(1+x^2) > t^4/(1+t^2)$ for $t < x < f(t)$ and sufficiently large $t$, 
we have $t < f(t) < t + 2 (1+t^2)/t^4$.  In particular $f(t) = t + O(1/t^2)$.  Now
from differentiating your equation using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$ f'(t) = \frac{t^4}{1+t^2} \frac{1+f(t)^2}{f(t)^4} = 1 + O(1/t^3) $$